# XSLT management - attaching metadata to a stylesheet for output and parameters

Tags: xslt

I am using about a dozen XSLT files to provide a large number of output formats. At the moment the user has to know the extension of the file format being exported to e.g. RTF, HTML, TXT.

I would also like to use parameters to allow more options.  If I can embed the metadata in the XSL file itself then I can pick up the details by scanning through the files.

Here is what I am thinking about. In this example the program would have to parse the comments for the required information.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Title: Export to Rich Text Format -->
<!-- Description: This Stylesheet converts to a Rich Text Format format which may be used in a word processor such as Word -->
<!-- FileFormat: RTF -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:param name="CompanyName"/> <!-- Format:String, Description: Company name to be inserted in the footer -->
<xsl:param name="DateDue"/> <!-- Format:Date-yyyy-mm-dd, Description: Date Due -->
<xsl:param name="IncludePicture">true</xsl:param><!-- Format:Boolean, Description: Do you want to include a graphical representation? -->
  <xsl:template match="/">
  <!-- Stuff -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Are there any standards out there? Do I need to butcher more than one (Dublin Core with a smattering of XML Schema)?

P.S. the project this is being applied to is [Argumentative](https://sourceforge.net/projects/argumentative/).

Comment: Very good question (+1). See my answer for a beter solution how to represent metadata in XSLT.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Here is what I am thinking about. In
>   this example the program would have to
>   parse the comments for the required
>   information.

You *don't* need to code the metadata within comments.

**Metadata can be specified as part of the XSLT stylesheet using ordinary XML markup -- as rich in structure and meaning as we need**.

Here is an example how to do that:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:meta="my:meta">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <meta:metadata>
   <title>Title: Export to Rich Text Format </title>
   <description>
    This Stylesheet converts to a Rich Text
    Format format which may be used in a word processor
    such as Word
   </description>
   <fileFormat>RTF</fileFormat>
   <parameters>
     <parameter name="CompanyName" format="xs:string"
      Description="Company name to be inserted in the footer"/>

     <parameter name="DateDue" format="xs:date"
      Description="Date Due"/>

     <parameter name="IncludePicture" format="xs:boolean"
      Description="Do you want to include a graphical representation?"/>
   </parameters>
 </meta:metadata>

 <xsl:param name="CompanyName"/>
 <xsl:param name="DateDue"/>
 <xsl:param name="IncludePicture" select="true"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vMetadata" select=
      "document('')/*/meta:metadata"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  This is a demo how we can access and use the metadats.

  Metadata --> Description:

  "<xsl:copy-of select="$vMetadata/description"/>"
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the result is**:

```
  This is a demo how we can access and use the metadats.

  Metadata --> Description:

  "
    This Stylesheet converts to a Rich Text
    Format format which may be used in a word processor
    such as Word
   "
```

**Do note**:

1. Any element that is in a namespace (of course not the no-namespace and not the xsl namespace) can be specified at the global level of any xslt stylesheet.
2. Such elements can be accessed using the xslt function `document()`.

Comment: A wonderful answer.  I particularly liked the introspective "document('')/*/meta:metadata"
Many thanks

Comment: @John_Hartley: Actually, The code was badly formatted -- I have fixed the formatting now.